# Importing text from file into a NVARCHAR(MAX) column; getting � for characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We're moving are article content from files into a NVARCHAR(MAX) column on our content_articles table. The content is inserted via a simple stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateArticleContent]
    @ArticleID VARCHAR(50), 
    @ArticleText NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE content_article
    SET article_content = @ArticleText
    WHERE article_id = @ArticleID
END
GO
```

The function that grabs the article file, text, and then calls the stored procedure can be found here:

```
private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var dbSelected = ServerDropDown.SelectedItem.ToString();
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dbSelected))
{
    OutputTextBox.Text = "Cannnot reach db.";
}
else
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var articlesConvertedPath = string.Format(@"{0}\ArticlesConverted", FolderPathTextBox.Text);
    var articlesConvertedDir = new DirectoryInfo(articlesConvertedPath);
    var articlesConvertedFiles = articlesConvertedDir.GetFiles();
    var articlesConvertedNames = articlesConvertedFiles.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

    var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FolderPathTextBox.Text);
    var sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[dbSelected].ConnectionString;
    var con = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
    con.Open();

    foreach (var currFile in dirInfo.GetFiles().Where(x => !articlesConvertedNames.Contains(x.Name)))
    {
        sb.AppendLine(currFile.Name.Replace(".asp", string.Empty));
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(currFile.FullName))
        {
            var articleText = sr.ReadToEnd()
                .Replace("<!--#include file=\"../include/engine_article_header.asp\"-->", string.Empty)
                .Replace("<!--#include file=\"../include/engine_article_footer.asp\"-->", string.Empty)
                .Replace("<img src=\"", "<img src=\"http://www.oandp.com/");

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UpdateArticleContent", con))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.Add("@ArticleID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = currFile.Name.Replace(".asp", string.Empty);
                command.Parameters.Add("@ArticleText", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = articleText;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        var copyFilePath = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", articlesConvertedPath, currFile.Name);
        if (File.Exists(copyFilePath))
        {
            File.Delete(copyFilePath);
            File.Copy(currFile.FullName, copyFilePath);
        }
        else
        {
            File.Copy(currFile.FullName, copyFilePath);
        }
    }
    con.Close();
    sb.AppendLine("Finished!");

    OutputTextBox.Text = sb.ToString();
}
}
```

It's taking the simplest of characters, like a dash or quote, and making them �.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, it seemed like it would be pretty straight forward.

Little tidbits: Running SQL Server 2008 R2

Does anyone know why, with the information above, the � is replacing non-alphanumeric characters?

Comment: What encoding is your table/columns? Do they all match?

Comment: Are they getting read correctly on the C# side?

Comment: yep, its enconding issues

Comment: @FrankerZ Encoding is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. Same as table.

Comment: It's likely NOT a problem with SQL, but whatever chain of processes you're using to collect and inject the data into the procedure. Usually when I see one of those, it's because a conversion beween encoding types (such as UTF-8 or win-1252) causes a 4 byte character to be compressed into fewer bytes, and then when the downstream interpreter (be it a website, SSIS, an email client, etc) tries to interpret the character in a 4-byte encoding, it can't make heads or tails of it. That's a short answer to a hard problem. You might also check out  http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html

Comment: @SledgeHammer while breaking through the code, the "articleText string shows the �. So... something to do with the StreamReader?

Comment: Another possibility it might be a "non-standard" quote. Some foreign keyboards and stuff will put in something that looks to the naked eye like a dash or something but byte for byte is something completely different. Either way, it's still an encoding issue, but it might be something to bear in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You guys pointed me in the right direction. All I had to do in the StreamReader was Encoding.Default. THANK YOU!